The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in './src/models/userModel.js'


Failed to compile.
./src/models/userModel.js
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime 
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation
The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in './src/models/userModel.js'.
Import trace for requested module:
  ./src/models/userModel.js
  ./src/auth.js
  ./src/middleware.js
> Build failed because of webpack errors
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1


Version-
"mongoose": "^8.3.3",
"next": "14.2.3",
While deploying my app through Vercel, I encountered this error. The app runs smoothly in localhost, but it encounters issues during deployment.
Technologies in this app -
Next 14,nextauth, mongoose
This is my github repo - https://github.com/naimursardul/authentication-nextauthjs
You can easily check the repo because the app is very small.
I have tried several methods to solve the issue, but none of them have worked.

https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/3398

The simplest way is to create a route and then call it in the middleware.
example


import dbConnect from "@/__backend/db";
import UserModel from "@/__backend/model/userModel";
import { srhResponse } from "@/__backend/util";
import { resStatus } from "@/interfaces";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  await dbConnect();
  const body = await request.json();
  const {email, password} = body;
  
  const models = await UserModel.findOne({ email, password }).populate(['role', 'gender']);
  if (!models) {
    return srhResponse({ error: "User not found." }, resStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  return srhResponse(models, resStatus.OK);
}



in auth.ts file


Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: {},
        password: {},
      },
      authorize: async (credentials): Promise<User | null> => {
        let user = null
        // if (credentials.email === "admin" && credentials.password === "admin") {
        //   user = {  name: "Admin", gender: 'male', email: "admin", role: "admin", dateOfBirth: Date.now().toString() }
        // }

        //  try {
        //    user = await UserModel.findOne({
        //       email: credentials?.email,
        //     }).populate(['role', 'gender']).select("+password");
        //  } catch (error) {
        //   throw new Error("User not found.");

        //  }

        const userRes = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/auth', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(credentials), headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })

        if (userRes.ok) {
          const json = await userRes.json()
          user= json.data;
        }

        // if (credentials.email && credentials.password) {
        //   user = await UserModel.findOne({
        //     email: credentials?.email,
        //   }).populate(['role', 'gender']).select("+password");
        // }

        if (!user) {
          // No user found, so this is their first attempt to login
          // meaning this is also the place you could do registration
          throw new Error("User not found.")
        }

        // if (user.password !== credentials.password) {
        //   // Passwords don't match
        //   throw new Error("Password is incorrect.")
        // }

        // return user object with their profile data
        return {name: user.name, email: user.email, dateOfBirth: user.dateOfBirth, gender: user.gender.type, role: user.role.type}
      },
    }),




i've got the same issue
Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation
The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in './lib/db.ts'.

I also got the same issue on production, localhost is okay..running latest version of next with mongoose

please share the solution. why this error is showing on the production mode
The error was caused by importing 'mongoose/dist/browser.umd.js' in './src/models/UserModel.js'.
